# How to convert varchar to array in Presto Athena

Tags: arrays, json, presto, amazon-athena, trino

My data is in `VARCHAR` format. I want to split both the elements of this array so that I can then extract a key value from the JSON.

#### Data format

```
[
  {
    "skuId": "5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1",
    "unitPrice": 0,
    "id": "5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1",
    "quantity": "1"
  },
  
{
    "skuId": "182784738484wefhdchs4848",
    "unitPrice": 50,
    "id": "5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1",
    "quantity": "4"
  },
]
```

For example I want to extract `skuid` from the above column.
So my data after extraction should look like:

```
1 5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1
2 182784738484wefhdchs4848
```

Cast to array doesn't work either:

```sql
SELECT CAST(col AS ARRAY)
```

gives the following error:

> Unknown type: array

So I am not able to un-nest the array.

How do I do solve this problem in *Presto Athena*?

Comment: were. you able to get a solution to extract the data on Athena? I just tried the below solution and ended up in an error: `INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast JSON to array(row(skuid varchar))`

Answer (score 11):

You can use a combination of [parsing the value as JSON](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse), casting it to a structured SQL type (array/map/row), and [UNNEST WITH ORDINALITY](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) to extract the elements from the array as separate rows. Note that this only works if the array elements in the JSON payload don't have a trailing commas. Your example has one but it is removed from the example below.

```sql
WITH data(value) AS (VALUES
 '[
    {
      "skuId": "5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1",
      "unitPrice": 0,
      "id": "5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1",
      "quantity": "1"
    },
    {
      "skuId": "182784738484wefhdchs4848",
      "unitPrice": 50,
      "id": "5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1",
      "quantity": "4"
    }
  ]'
),
parsed(entries) AS (
  SELECT cast(json_parse(value) AS array(row(skuId varchar)))
  FROM data
)
SELECT ordinal, skuId
FROM parsed, UNNEST(entries) WITH ORDINALITY t(skuId, ordinal)
```

produces:

```
 ordinal |          skuId
---------+--------------------------
       1 | 5bc87ae20d298a283c297ca1
       2 | 182784738484wefhdchs4848
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Martin:  I have tried executing snippet provided by you on aws athena. I get an error : `INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast JSON to array(row(skuid varchar))`

Comment: AWS Athena has two versions, which map to specific versions of Presto. Athena version 1 used Presto 0.172; Athena version 2 uses version 0.217. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/engine-versions-reference.html) for details. Please check what version of Athena you're using and whether the corresponding version of Presto supports these sorts of operations.