# Athena-Querying a table with JSON in one column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

I have a parquet file with the following format

```
id = 2a1ed0848022
raw_value:
[{"state":"MO","city":"O Fallon","location_name":"Jackson Hewitt Tax Service","top_category":"Accounting, Tax Preparation, Bookkeeping, and Payroll Services"},
{"state":"IL","city":"Collinsville","location_name":"L E Smith Jewelry","top_category":"Jewelry, Luggage, and Leather Goods Stores"},
{"state":"MO","city":"O Fallon","location_name":"Bagwasi Family Eyecare","top_category":"Health and Personal Care Stores"},
{"state":"MO","city":"O Fallon","location_name":"Rally's Drive-In Restaurants","top_category":"Restaurants and Other Eating Places"},
{"state":"IL","city":"Collinsville","location_name":"BP","top_category":"Gasoline Stations"}
```

I would like to create a table in Athena on this parquet file and run a query like this

```
select maid from test12 where state="MD" and city="Baltimore".
```

How can I search state and city from the second column which has nested JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is to use `UNNEST`. I'm assuming that `raw_value` is typed as `array<struct<state:string,city:string,location_name:string,top_category:string>>`.

```
SELECT id
FROM the_table CROSS JOIN UNNEST(raw_value) rv (location)
WHERE location.state = 'MD' AND city = 'Baltimore'
```

Using `UNNEST` like this expands each row in the table to one row per element in the array.

If `raw_value` is a string column, you need to parse it first. You can find an example of this in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56176204/1109