# Extract values from json_array in Athena

Tags: hive, presto, amazon-athena

I have JSON data as follows:

`[{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":1},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":2},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":3},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":4},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":5},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":6},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":7}]`

I need to extract values of `dayOfWeek`, `start` & `end`
Tried the solution suggested for [Unable to convert varchar to array in Presto Athena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56167704/unable-to-convert-varchar-to-array-in-presto-athena) but no luck.

Expected Result:

```
dayOfWeek   start   end
1   11:00   22:00
2   11:00   22:00
3   11:00   22:00
4   11:00   22:00
5   11:00   22:00
6   11:00   22:00
7   11:00   22:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query. Verified with version 0.172.

```sql
WITH data(value) AS (VALUES
 '[{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":1},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":2},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":3},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":4},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":5},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":6},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":7}]'
),
parsed(c1) AS (
  SELECT cast(json_parse(value) AS array(json)) 
  FROM data
)
SELECT 
  json_extract_scalar(json1, '$.dayOfWeek') AS "dayOfWeek"
 ,json_extract_scalar(json1, '$.all.start') AS "start"
 ,json_extract_scalar(json1, '$.all.end') AS "end"
FROM parsed, unnest(c1) as t(json1)
```

Comment: With an additional `id` column, How to write query. 

Expected: ```id,dayOfWeek,start,end```


```WITH data(id, value) AS (VALUES
 ('1558', '[{"all":{"end":"21:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":1},{"all":{"end":"21:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":2}]'),
 ('1559', '[{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":1},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":2}]'),
 ('1560', '[{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"15:00"},"dayOfWeek":2},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"15:00"},"dayOfWeek":3},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"15:00"},"dayOfWeek":4}]'))SELECT id,  value
  FROM data```

Comment: You can simply pass the `id` column to subsequent SELECT query.

Comment: WITH data(id, value) AS (VALUES
 ('1558', '[{"all":{"end":"21:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":1},{"all":{"end":"21:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":2}]'),
 ('1559', '[{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":1},{"all":{"end":"22:00","start":"11:00"},"dayOfWeek":2}]'))
 ,
parsed(id, c1) AS (
  SELECT id, cast(json_parse(value) AS array(json)) 
  FROM data
)
SELECT 
  id, json_extract_scalar(json1, '$.dayOfWeek') AS "dayOfWeek"
 ,json_extract_scalar(json1, '$.all.start') AS "start"
 ,json_extract_scalar(json1, '$.all.end') AS "end"
FROM parsed, unnest(c1) as t(json1)